# On vscode :'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

So, I take a TypeScript tutorial and came across an issue, if I write one of this phrases:

```
tsc --init
tsc filename.ts
tsc --help
tsc --version
```

I get this error:

```
tsc is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I wrote `npm install -g typescript` in cmd but again, if I write something with `tsc`, I get the same error. I change `"command":"npm"` to `"tsc"` but this not helped.

I working in vscode on Windows. I don't know what I can do.

Comment: edit: i reinstall node.js on my mashine. it working now

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode use:

```
npx tsc -v
```

In cmd use:

```
tsc -v
```